# Mac terminal and r show different gdal versions

Tags: r, version, homebrew, gdal, hdf

I am trying to read a .hdf file into R using:

```
gdalUtils::get_subdatasets()
```

but I am left with this error:

```
ERROR 4: `/var/folders/24/9_h4zhq564g3zpvqp6jmbm0c0000gn/T//RtmpibWWKQ/MODIStsp/HDFs/MCD12Q1.A2014001.h18v04.006.2018146020544.hdf' not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/var/folders/24/9_h4zhq564g3zpvqp6jmbm0c0000gn/T//RtmpibWWKQ/MODIStsp/HDFs/MCD12Q1.A2014001.h18v04.006.2018146020544.hdf'.
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In system(cmd, intern = TRUE) :
  running command '"/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/3.2.0/bin/gdalinfo" "/var/folders/24/9_h4zhq564g3zpvqp6jmbm0c0000gn/T//RtmpibWWKQ/MODIStsp/HDFs/MCD12Q1.A2014001.h18v04.006.2018146020544.hdf"' had status 1
```

I have had issues with gdal before, and was forced to download and use an older version of gdal to get the above function to work properly. In mac terminal, running

```
gdalinfo --version
```

returns

```
GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01
```

I assume there is a build problem here. When I run the following command in the R Console:

```
getGDALVersionInfo()
```

I am returned:

```
"GDAL 3.2.0, released 2020/10/26"
```

Is there a method to "unlink" gdal from R and then relink it to the older version noted in my Mac terminal?

There is a similar problem posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327253/rungdal-returns-gdalinfo-failed-unable-to-open-hdf-file), but the (unaccepted) answer is ambigious: "You need to uninstall gdalinfo on your mac environment and use R gdalinfo and dont forget to restart your R after uninstall it"

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got with fresh installations of R and gdal on my Mojave machine, hope it helps:

```
$ r

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> system("gdalinfo --version")
GDAL 3.2.0, released 2020/10/26
> getGDALVersionInfo()
Error in getGDALVersionInfo() :
  could not find function "getGDALVersionInfo"
```

```
$ ls -al $(which gdalinfo)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 rchen  staff  33 Nov 18 21:11 /usr/local/bin/gdalinfo -> ../Cellar/gdal/3.2.0/bin/gdalinfo
```